# CSRF-Prevention: No origin and referer header - how handle?

Tags: security, header, server, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm trying to enhance my CSRF-prevention by *checking the origin and referer header* serverside before accepting or blocking requests from the client.

Referring to [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) site at owasp.org *one should block all requests that do neither include an origin or a referer header*:

> What to do when Both Origin and Referer Aren't Present
>
> If neither of these headers is present, which should be VERY rare, you can either accept or block the request. We recommend blocking, (...)

BUT ... when I now open a new tab and try to load my page for first time, my request has no origin or referer header, thus my first request gets be blocked.

Question: How should these cases be handled? Or have I missunderstood something?

Note: I use CSRF-token-protection, this question is just about header checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but when you first load your page, there should be no state-changing request. For that reason, the request should be allowed.

Your filter should first check if the request is state-changing (put, delete, etc), and then check for appropriate headers if it is.